# Upgraded java library to 1.19.0 and User model return types are all different

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm using the Java client library for the Directory API from here:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/admin/directory_v1

The com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.User model has changed from 1.16 to 1.19.

In the old version I used to be able to do this:

```
List<UserAddress> userAddressList = user.getAddresses();
for(UserAddress userAddress : userAddressList) {
    ///
}
```

But now user.getAddresses is returning an Object. Same deal for getOrganizations, phones, etc... These all return an Object which upon further inspection looks like:

```
List<ArrayMap<String, String>>
```

ArrayMap extends GenericJson.

What do I have to do to get at the UserAddress, other then going back to the previous version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug (from my point of view) in the latest versions. Use an older one like 1.16, 1.17 or the first 1.18 (latest 1.18 also have the bug).

Comment: I started at rev32 for 1.18.0 and worked my way up to find the most recent working version, which is: directory_v1-rev34-1.18.0-rc

Answer (score 0):

[The same thing happened in the C# client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620274/why-is-type-of-these-user-properties-object-addresses-emails-organizations-e) and back in May 2015 a Google developer named [Eric Koleda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/702875/eric-koleda) replied:

> A change to the backend had the unintended consequence of changing the discovery document for the service, making the addresses field (and others) being marked as type=any. This causes problems for strongly types languages like .NET, as you've found. The team is aware of the issue but it's unclear when a fix will be available.

However the C# client still has this problem, so I would assume the Java client does as well.

Here are a couple of issues I found in Google's issue tracker specifically for this problem in the Java client, but neither has seen any progress yet:

- [Issue 3645](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3645): Broken code generator for Directory API in Java client: User class lacking explicit types
- [Issue 3730](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3730): Latest version of the Directory API client returns Object instead of correct class